# Soccer tournament with an unspecified schedule

Tags: combinatorics

16 soccer teams are taking part in a tournament where teams play with each other once. Every team scores $n$ goals in their $n$-th play. What is the minimal total number of draws in the tournament?

As far as I understand, one needs to find the schedule of plays which minimizes the number of draws. I see it like this. Team 1 plays with team 2 (with the final score 1:1), which gives the first draw. Then team 1 plays consequently with teams 3,4,...16 winning each time with the scores 2:1,3:1,...,15:1, respectively. Then team 2 plays with team 3 (with the score 2:2), which gives the second draw. Then team 2 plays with the remaining teams, winning all matches. The pattern repeat until we have the final match (a draw) between teams 15 and 16. This approach gives 15 draws.

However, I cannot show that this is the optimal schedule producing the minimal number of draws.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the schedule with only 2 draws.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline I-II&1-1&\text{first-match}\\\hline
II-III&2-1&\text{pattern-1}\\
III-IV&2-1\\
IV-V&2-1\\
\cdots&\cdots\\
XV-XVI&2-1\\\hline
XVI-II&3-2&\text{pattern-2}\\
I-III&3-2&\\\hline
II-IV&4-3&\text{pattern-3}\\
III-V&4-3\\
\cdots&\cdots\\
XIII-XIV&4-3\\
XIV-XVI&4-3\\
XV-I&4-3\\\hline
II-XVI&3-2&\text{pattern-2}\\
III-I&3-2\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\text{pattern-3}\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\text{pattern-2}\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\text{pattern-3}\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\text{pattern-2}\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\text{pattern-3}\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\text{pattern-2}\\\hline
II-IV&16-15&\text{pattern-3}\\
\cdots&\cdots\\
XV-I&16-15\\\hline
I-XVI&16-16&\text{final-match}\\\hline
\end{array}$$
You can't avoid the first and last match, but rest all you can, however large the number of players may be.The minimum is 2.